# Select multiple checkboxes for a Cucumber test

Tags: html, ruby, cucumber, webrat

Working on a big project using cucumber for our frontend tests.
My question about this, that i have a search page with a group of checkboxes, like "select your sites:", with fieldname like "sites[]"
When I click "Submit" Cucumber default submits the last checkbox as selected when I set up the form to have all checkboxes default selected.
Is there a way to have cucumber select multiple checkboxes with these array notation?